# How should log4j.properties  look like?

Tags: java, log4j, log-viewer

After discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790920/how-to-start-using-chainsaw-for-log4j) I still cannot configure my program/chainsaw

When I start ChainSaw I choose

- let me use a simple Receiver on port 4445

And in my program i set configuration:

`PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");`

And finally run program, and click `Simple Receiver` in Chainsaw

log4j.properties version1

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, server

log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.server.Port=4445
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

log4j.properties version2

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, zeroconf, chainsaw
# Socket Appender
log4j.appender.chainsaw=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.chainsaw.remoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.chainsaw.port=4445
log4j.appender.chainsaw.locationInfo=true
```

none of them work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
log4j.threshold=ALL
log4j.debug = true
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, chainsaw
# Socket Appender
log4j.appender.chainsaw=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.chainsaw.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.chainsaw.Port=4445
log4j.appender.chainsaw.LocationInfo=true
```

This is good example of chainsaw configuration which is also required:

http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.com/2010/02/viewingmonitoring-your-log4j-generated.html

Comment: Unfortunately I got `log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.zeroconf
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "zeroconf".`

Comment: Take it out. It is not configured.

Comment: What does log4j debug tells you, if anything?

Comment: I have no idea how to check it. But if I have ChainSaw opened, a new tab should appear in it? I don't have anything like this. maybe the reason is that [Socket Receiver is inactive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796027/why-is-socket-receiver-inactive-in-chainsaw)?

Comment: Did you, btw, configure chainsaw for Log4J ingest.

Comment: Check that blog post I added to my answer. It is pretty recent.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.4, Log4j now supports configuration via properties files. Note that the property syntax is NOT the same as the syntax used in Log4j 1.

```
appender.server.type=Socket
appender.server.name=server
appender.server.port=4445
appender.server.host=localhost
appender.server.reconnectDelayMillis=10000

...

rootLogger.appenderRef.server.ref = server
```

You might have a problem with `reconnectionDelayMillis`. In [logging-log4j-dev mailing list archives](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-dev/201702.mbox/%3CF98E89D5-CCD5-46E0-A38E-7141421101DE@gmail.com%3E) I found out that:

> The documentation
>   (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender)
>   still has the parameter listed as "reconnectionDelayMillis" but the
>   code is now obviously looking for "reconnectDelayMillis". I'm going to
>   change my config to use the new name, but I thought I'd point out the
>   disconnect as it had me confused for a bit. Thanks - Sam

This might be fixed/unified already, but I haven't checked that in the newer versions of log4j. If you encounter any problem try using `reconnectDelayMillis`.

More detailed example can be found under [**Configuration with Properties**](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties).