# Why is Socket Receiver inactive in Chainsaw?

Tags: java, log4j

When I start ChainSaw (using a simple Receiver on port 4445)

I see its: properties

```
active  false
class   class org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver
connectedSocketDetails  []
listener    
loggerRepository    org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy@1c3dc66
name    SocketReceiver
paused  false
port    4445
threshold   TRACE
```

Probably I cannot see my logs due to the fact that Socket Receiver is inactive. How could I change it? If you are experienced in using Chainsaw could you also check if my log4j.properties are ok?

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, server

log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.server.Port=4445
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Web Start version of Chainsaw?  We are going to be releasing an updated of Chainsaw soon, with a lot of new features - would you mind downloading the developer snapshot and giving that a try?  It's not yet available via Web Start.

When Chainsaw starts you should be prompted with a (new) configuration dialog where you can ask it to set up a socket receiver and provide the port, and tell it to always use this configuration.

Here's the link to the developer snapshot:
http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: Scott, I still have the same problem. I choose: `receive events from the network` by `Socket Server 4445` (my `log4j.properties` is in my question). What is wrong? I cannot see my logs.

Comment: I'd check netstat to make sure that socket isn't already in use by something, and that you don't have a firewall blocking that port. I'd also make sure you're using a 'recent' log4j.jar, as SocketAppender sends serialized LoggingEvents over the network, and the serial form did change a long time ago (can you use log4j 1.2.17 on the send side? that'd take that out of the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property file.when you start chainsaw v2 web start check radio button with let me use simple receiver  and select socket receiver and then ok.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CHAINSAW_CLIENT

log4j.appender.CHAINSAW_CLIENT=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.CHAINSAW_CLIENT.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.CHAINSAW_CLIENT.Port=4445
log4j.appender.CHAINSAW_CLIENT.LocationInfo=true
```